# Fill SVG path based on the length of the video?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, jsx

I'm trying to create a custom progress bar for the HTML5 video tag. The progress bar doesn't need any controls, it's just an SVG that I'd like to fill as the video progresses.

The video is a React component:

```
    import React, {useRef} from 'react'
   
    
    const VideoSection = () => {
      const videoRef = useRef()
      const handlePlayVideo = () => videoRef.current.play()
      return (
        <div>
           <button onClick={handlePlayVideo}>
            Play video
          </button>
          
          <video src='./video.mp4' ref={videoRef}/>
          
          //The SVG I'd like to animate

          <svg width="595" height="28" viewBox="0 0 595 28" fill="none" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 14C0 6.26801 6.26801 0 14 0H595V28H14C6.26801 28 0 21.732 0 
            14V14Z" fill="#072760"/>
          </svg>

          
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default VideoSection
```

Or is there an alternative way to approach/build the progress bar? Thanks!

Comment: It will be nice to know more about it. In the case you intend to change the color from red to green you can use hsl colors where you change the hue value from 0 (red) to 130 or 140 for green

Comment: Maybe the standard HTML ``<progress>`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress